# Vim Question: Sparkup doesn't work for files opened from a running Vim session

Tags: vim, nerdtree

If I were to open a file with Vim from the command prompt (eg: vim ~/.vimrc), the Sparkup text generation seems to work perfectly fine. For example if I insert:

```
html:xs
```

and then push control + e, sparkup generates a nice HTML strict boilerplate. However if I then split to another file from the running Vim session, Sparkup stops working in the newly opened file. It's totally possible that other plugins lose their functionality as well. Here is my .vimrc file:

```
set nocompatible    " use vim defaults
set number          " show line numbers
set tags=tags;$HOME/.vim/tags/ "recursively searches directory for 'tags' file
set expandtab       " tabs are converted to spac
set tabstop=4       " numbers of spaces of tab character
set shiftwidth=4    " numbers of spaces to (auto)indent
set showcmd         " display incomplete commands
set incsearch       " do incremental searching
set ruler           " show the cursor position all the time
set numberwidth=4   " line numbering takes up 5 spaces
set ignorecase      " ignore case when searching
set nowrap          " stop lines from wrapping
set incsearch       " show search matches as you type

call pathogen#helptags()
call pathogen#runtime_append_all_bundles()

filetype on            " enables filetype detection
filetype plugin on     " enables filetype specific plugins
filetype plugin indent on " Loads pyflake-vim's ftplugin files automatically when a Python buffer is opened

syntax on                 " syntax highlighing
colorscheme default

nmap <silent> <c-y> :NERDTreeToggle<CR>
nmap <silent> <c-o> :OpenBookmark 

" TagList Plugin Configuration
let Tlist_Ctags_Cmd='/usr/bin/ctags'       " point taglist to ctags
let Tlist_GainFocus_On_ToggleOpen = 1      " Focus on the taglist when its toggled
let Tlist_Close_On_Select = 1              " Close when something's selected
let Tlist_Use_Right_Window = 1             " Project uses the left window
let Tlist_File_Fold_Auto_Close = 1         " Close folds for inactive files

" Omnicompletion functions
set ofu=syntaxcomplete#complete
autocmd FileType python set omnifunc=pythoncomplete#Complete
autocmd FileType javascript set omnifunc=javascriptcomplete#CompleteJS
autocmd FileType html set omnifunc=htmlcomplete#CompleteTags
autocmd FileType css set omnifunc=csscomplete#CompleteCSS

au FileType py set expandtab

map <F2> :previous<CR>                  " map F2 to open previous buffer
map <F3> :next<CR>                      " map F3 to open next buffer
map <F5> :TlistToggle<CR>               " map F5 to toggle the Tag Listing
map <silent><C-Left> <C-T>              " taglist - map Ctrl-LeftArrow to jump to the method/property under your cursor
map <silent><C-Right> <C-]>             " taglist - map Ctrl-RhitArrow to jump back to your source code

" Easy window navigation
map <C-h> <C-w>h
map <C-j> <C-w>j
map <C-k> <C-w>k
map <C-l> <C-w>l

" When vimrc is edited, reload it
autocmd! bufwritepost vimrc source ~/.vim_runtime/vimrc

highlight SpellBad term=reverse ctermbg=Gray ctermfg=Red
```

And here are some other plugins I have inside ~/.vim/bundles:

IndexedSearch     nerdtree          snipmate.vim      vim-css-color     vim-git           vim-rails         vim-ruby-debugger vim-supertab      vim-tcomment
gist              pyflakes-vim      textile.vim       vim-cucumber      vim-haml          vim-repeat        vim-shoulda       vim-surround      vim-vividchalk
jquery            pysmell           vim-align         vim-fugitive      vim-markdown      vim-ruby          vim-sparkup       vim-taglist

Comment: Do you get some error messages? Also what does `:!pwd` returns in the first buffer? And in the second? And `:!echo $PATH` in both buffers?

Comment: When I use the shortcut, it duplicates the contests of the line below, one character at a time. No error message...pwd and the $PATH are the same for both buffers. Verbose map reveals the Sparkup mapping in the working buffer, but not in the non-working buffer. I don't see any mapping for <c-e> in the non-working one, actually.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can it be that this plugin is bound to a given FileType and that when you change window the FileType is not the same?

If it doesn't work, try adding your plugin to ftplugins.

Comment: the plugin is set for HTML files. If I try to split into an existing HTML file with a standard HTML strict boilerplate from an open buffer, it doesn't work. If I just open up an HTML file at the commandline, then my Sparkup map loads just fine.

Comment: Try doing manually :setfiletype html in the non-working buffer and retry; it might be that the autocommand of the plugin is not correct.

Comment: No go... on 'setfiletype html'. The problem seems to lie in the fact that that sparkup.vim file isn't sourced from new buffers that I open from a running Vim session. If I explicitly type ":so ~/.vim/bundle/vim-sparkup/plugin/html/sparkup.vim" then it works. I then tried moving sparkup.vim and sparkup.py up one directory (so that it resides in "/plugin rather than /plugin/html", thinking that maybe it is a filetype issue, but still no go. I'm perplexed!

Comment: I don't know enough of the internals of vim to help you.. last attempt: put it into .vim/ftplugin and see if it works.

Comment: Good news... your last suggestion worked! Don't know why, but it did ;)

Comment: I found the answer a few days ago, and I thought I posted it, but I guess not. The gist is that vim settings inside the plugin folder get loaded only once at startup. On the other hand, vim settings in ftplugin folders get loaded on a per file basis. so when I split into a new buffer, it loaded the appropriate vim settings. woohoo! thanks for the clue

Comment: Hi, mine was just an intuition, it is nice that you found why it works, thanks for explaining it :)